# Using $(this) instead $('.article') in this code didn't work?

Tags: javascript

```
var main = function(){
$('.article').click(function(){
    //$('.article').removeClass('current');
    $(this).removeClass('current');
    $('.description').hide();

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).children('.description').show();
});
$('.article').dblclick(function(){
    //$('.description').hide();
    $(this).children('.description').hide();            
});
```

};
$(document).ready(main);

This code is make a table arcodition like this http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-4hxyb/0/5?content_from=make-an-interactive-website%3Ajquery-events click fullcreen you see that using $(this).removeClass('current') instead $('.article').removeClass('current'). this keyword that reference to the 'article' class why using like that it didn't reference to 'article' class, must using '.artilce'. Can someone explain it, thanks!

Comment: If you have more elements with class `article` `$(this)` will apply for just clicked one. where as `$('.article')` will apply for all elements having class `article`.

Comment: Thanks for explain that to me

Comment: So you got your fault.

Answer (score 0):

here you have a simplified code showing that it works

```
var main = function(){
$('.article').click(function(){
    // below will change all with class article to green
    // $('.article').addClass('green')

    // with this it only changes the clicked one to green
    //$(this).addClass('green');

    // below will remove red-class from clicked .article
    //$(this).removeClass('red');

    //below will remove red-class from all elements with .article
    $('.article').removeClass('red');
});

}; $(document).ready(main);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tgLckfgz/2/

Comment: I know it work but like your code but that I want using $(this).removeClass() when you clicked that will change bg of article but using $('.article').removeClass() it just change bg the article was clicked. Can you explain why, thanks!

Comment: No its not like that, by using $('.article').removeClass() it will remove from all elements with class .article, check my update

Comment: main info is :  $(this) refers to the actual clicked element, $('.article') refers to all elements with class "article"